# Why do my two ssh public keys have the same beginning?

Tags: ssh, encryption

I was updating the authorized_keys file on my server with the public key for the new laptop I got and I was surprised to discover that the two public keys began the same:

```
# key 1
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQ....
#
# key 2
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQ....
```

What's the story on `AAAAB3...` etc? With some searching online, I see that others keys start the same, too. Does it explain the algorithm or version or something?

Comment: For what it's worth, I have 7 keys generated over the space of a few years, on various computers, and they all start with `AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAA` so I'm guessing it's some kind of common algo type/version identifier...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is actually a header that defines what kind of key this is. If you check out the Public Key Algorithm section of [RFC 4253](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-6.6) we can see that for RSA keys

> The "ssh-rsa" key format has the following specific encoding:
>
> ```
>  string    "ssh-rsa"
>  mpint     e
>  mpint     n
> ```
>
> Here the 'e' and 'n' parameters form the signature key blob.

In fact, if you Base64 decode the string "B3NzaC1yc2E" you will see it translates into ASCII as "ssh-rsa". Presumably the "AAAA" represents some kind of header so the application can know where exactly in the data stream to start processing the key.

Comment: This seems remarkably similar to what I said, including the link to the RFC.

Comment: @larsks: Apparently you hit submit while I was still writing mine.

Comment: "Presumably the "AAAA" represents some kind of header"...  Yup.  Some more details at https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/5948/109990

Answer (score 18):

The SSH public key format is documented in [RFC 4253](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-6.6), and summarized somewhat [here](https://blog.oddbit.com/post/2011-05-08-converting-openssh-public-keys/).  The PEM encoded data consists of a number of (length,data) pairs, and the first pair encodes the algorithm name, which is going to be something like `ssh-rsa` or `ssh-dsa`.

This means that the initial part of the public key data for all ssh keys is going to be similar.

Comment: I found keys starting with "MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAtO" what would that be?

Comment: You've provided insufficient data for me to answer that question. You can follow the instructions in [the linked article](https://blog.oddbit.com/post/2011-05-08-converting-openssh-public-keys/) for decoding it yourself, or you can just post it here (it is, after all, a *public* key) if you want me to look at it.

Comment: I forgot what key that was, but considering the article I think it was PKCS#1 PEM encoded as the example there starts roughly the same.

Comment: https://www.thedigitalcatonline.com/blog/2021/06/03/public-key-cryptography-openssh-private-keys/ shows something starting with "MII".  See also "Resources" on that page, showing multiple RFCs.  https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen.1 mentions multiple formats when looking at -m.  (Seeing that, I suspect that RFC 4253 might be an older approach.  Though at the moment, I haven't confirmed whether newer widespread behavior replaced that.)

Answer (score 12):

I did an overkill deep-dive into the format after following Scott's links for funsies. TLDR:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQ...
       |  "ssh-rsa"   |exponent|   modulus

ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIFKy...
           |   "ssh-ed25519"   |   32 byte public key
```

[RFC4231](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4251.txt) specifies the two data types used:

- `string`:
  Arbitrary length binary string.  Strings are allowed to contain
  arbitrary binary data, including null characters and 8-bit
  characters.
- `mpint`:
  Represents multiple precision integers in two's complement format,
  stored as a string, 8 bits per byte, MSB first. [...]

Both datatypes start with a `uint32` defining the length of data to come. Because that's usually overkill and you end up with lots of 0's (e.g. "abc" is stored as `\x00\x00\x00\x03abc`...), they end up as runs of `A`s in the base64-encoded payload (...`AAAAA2FiYwo`)

[RFC4253 sec 6.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-6.6) says the key is encoded as:

> The "ssh-rsa" key format has the following specific encoding:

> ```
> string    "ssh-rsa"
> mpint     e
> mpint     n
> ```

> Here the 'e' and 'n' parameters form the signature key blob. *[Ed: but the blob also seems to contain the string `"ssh-rsa"` as well...]*

> The resulting signature is encoded as follows:

> ```
> string    "ssh-rsa"
> string    rsa_signature_blob
> ```

> The value for 'rsa_signature_blob' is encoded as a string containing
> s *[Ed: don't know what s is.]* (which is an integer, without lengths or padding, unsigned, and in
> network byte order).

The more modern Ed25519 and Ed448 keys are defined in [RFC-8709](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8709#section-4) and have two fields:

- the constant string "ssh-ed25519" (or "ssh-ed448")
- the 32-byte (or 57-byte) public key as a string

#### `"ssh-rsa"`

The string `ssh-rsa` is converted to `\x00\x00\x00\x07ssh-rsa`, which then encodes to `AAAAB3NzaC1yc2E=`, so all ssh-rsa keys should start with that.

#### `e`, the public exponent

Usually something like 3, 17, 257, 65537. Those numbers get encoded as below (with the trailing offset from above)

- 3 → `'\x00\x00\x00\x01\x03'` → `AAAABAw`
- 17 → `'\x00\x00\x00\x01\x11'` → `AAAABEQ`
- 257 → `'\x00\x00\x00\x02\x01\x01'` → `AAAACAQE`
- 65537/0x10001 → `'\x00\x00\x00\x03\x01\x00\x01'` → `AAAADAQAB`

So, if you see "BAw", your exponent was 3, or "DAQAB" = 65537

#### `n`, the modulus (product of your two secret primes, factor this!)

`AAABAQ` after the above means that your key length is 2048 bits (and that your exponent was like DAQAB because of base64 padding). The entire rest of the base64 stuff is the exponent, there's nothing after.

Other modulus prefixes that may be common:

- `AAAAg` 1024 bits, e = 0x10001
- `AAAQI`: 2048 bits, e = 3